# Sum stack without last element

Tags: factor-lang

is there a possibility to sum up the stack without the last element? So for example if the stack has the following elements:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

After the operation the stack should look like this:

```
1 14
```

Answer (score 4):

```
USE: generalizations
1 2 3 4 5 datastack length 1 - nsum
```

Comment: The word was renamed so now it is: `1 2 3 4 5 get-datastack length 1 - nsum`